# How to append html to table td?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looping through a grids datasource and when it gets to ToFactory not being empty I need to add a div into its td cell. Below is the code that I am using to get the td at index 18 of its row

```
var data = this.dataSource.view();
for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    var dataItem = data[i];
    var tr = $("#QuickEntryGrid").find("[data-uid='" + dataItem.uid + "']");    
    if(dataItem.ToFactory != ""){
        let me = tr.find('td')[18];
        me.innerHtml = "<div class='abc'>1234</div>"; // Doesn't work
        console.log(me);
    }    
}
```

the variable me is

```
<td class role='gridcell'></td>
```

and what I would like to put in the td is

```
<div class='abc'>123</div>
```

and me should look like this

```
<td class role='gridcell'><div class='abc'>123</div></td>
```

but its not happening,

any idea's on why I am not getting this working? I have also tried

```
me.append("<div class='abc'>123</div>");
```

Comment: You missed to explain where's your `data-uid` element

Comment: What does `console.log(me)` show?

Comment: How about creating a [mcve]? Would it be too much markup?

Comment: @Barmar, <td class role='gridcell'></td>

Comment: Ahhh... It's a typo `innerHtml` should be `innerHTML` (look at the caps).

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette, yep you are right. I can't believe that I didn't catch that

Comment: Stick to jQuery: `tr.find("td").eq(18).html("<div class='abc'>1234</div>")`